# Comment traiter les questions politiquement chargées?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Exemple récent d'une telle question: [Le mot anglais « race »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52980/le-mot-anglais-race?noredirect=1#comment111141_52980)

Cette question a été fermée:

> Closed because there is nothing to be gained from a heated discussion of a question whose presuppositions can't reasonably be taken for granted

De mon point de vue, cette question est effectivement politiquement chargée, mais je n'ai pas l'impression que fermer les réponses ne résolve le problème. Au lieu d'avoir des explications constructives de pourquoi cette question est chargée, on a des débats en commentaires (qui sont nécessairement moins bien construits) et une seule réponse (celle qui a été faite le plus rapidement).

Dans ce cas je trouve que l'unique réponse est de qualité, mais on aurait très bien pu à la place avoir une réponse très mauvaise, postée à la hâte, qui serait donc l'unique réponse. La mécanique des votes de Stackexchange suppose qu'on puisse poster de nombreuses réponses, et que les mauvaises seront écrasées par les bonnes, mais en limitant à une unique réponse on ne peut rien en tirer.

Bref, je trouve que cette procédure est dommageable et mériterait d'être repensée. Comment pourrait-on faire autrement?

Answer (score 3):

La question est valide et appréciée.

J'ai fermé le fil en question après m'être occupé de 8 ou 9 autres flags qui s'étaient accumulés au cours d'un couple de jours, le plupart ayant impliqué une question ou un commentaire de ce genre (controversé) et les mêmes acteurs.

J'ai cru y prévoir une perte de temps et de civilité du genre qu'on appelle le « [sealioning](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning) ».

L'idée est un peu fausse qu'on aurait de la chance à avoir une réponse admissible au moment de fermeture : j'avais considéré sa qualité quand j'ai fermé la question.

Il se peut cependant que tu aies raison et que la fermeture crée une atmosphère d'incertitude ou même de répression. Si la communauté vote pour rouvir la question, souhaitant une telle discussion, elle sera rouverte et l'équipe de modération gardera un œil sur les développements.

Dans l'entretemps j'ai transféré les commentaires.

Answer (score 1):

La dernière question de l'OP est peut-être assez mal formulée (*Doit-on réduire des phrases entières à néant dans les traductions, ou simplement ignorer les directives plus ou moins officielles ... ?*").

Mais dans le simple contexte d'une question de langage et sachant que tous les intervenants ne sont pas tous de langue maternelle française, je suis assez naïf pour ne pas y voir forcement de connotation politique.

Le motif du retrait de la question est "opinion-based". Mais, cette affirmation concerne l'opinion éventuelle des lecteurs sur la formulation de la question et non sur le fait que la demande pose une question à laquelle on ne peut répondre qu'en fonction de ses propres goûts.

Comment: Je ne vois pas de mauvaise formulation dans "directives plus ou moins officielles ", ça dit bien ce que ça veut dire, ça exprime une prise de position politique, le PO aurait pu aussi choisir de citer des extraits des débats qui ont agité la France sur ce sujet depuis le début du millénaire et jusqu'au vote au parlement. Que ce choix soit conscient ou non de la part du PO, il n'empêche qu'il (ce choix) a été fait et qu'il (ce choix) exprime une opinion. Ignorer ce choix dans la réponse serait aussi prendre parti.

Comment: @None : Les directives les "plus officielles" concernent les textes legislatifs nouveaux et l'incitation à la haine raciale. Les "moins officielles" sont un quasi consensus  sur l'usage du mot. Mais, il n'y a évidemment rien de précis concernant la traduction depuis une langue étrangère. *Pourquoi donc faire à l'OP un procès d'intention basé sur la simple sensibilité du lecteur ?*